# Oneliner association from array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Coffeescript I can do this:

```
[one..., two] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# one = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# two = 5
```

Is there any way to do this (oneliner) in Ruby?

**EDIT**

I know that I can do this:

```
one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
two = one.slice!(-1)
```

**EDIT 2**

Oneliner could look like this:

```
two = (one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).slice!(-1)
```

but this seems too ugly for me.

Comment: does that mean that `one` is all variables to n-1?

Comment: yeah, I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
*one, two = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
one
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
two
# => 5
```

You can see some more explanations on `splat` and `array destructuring` [here](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/#array_destructuring)

Comment: Thank you, accepted because this answer contains more explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):002:0> *one, two = a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):003:0> one
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):004:0> two
=> 5
```

Comment: :) Thank you guys ... now I don't know whose answer should I accept ... both same and almost at the same time